# Flutter device daemon Crashed

Tags: android, flutter, daemon, resolve

I changed the directory name in which flutter is installed. After that, an error is occurring whenever I started the android studio. The error is *'**The Flutter device daemon cannot be started.**'* A screenshot is attached.

[image]

I am using a physical device for debugging connected through wifi network. I will be very grateful for helping me regarding this error.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command with your "Android Studio" path

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Android Studio"
```

Answer (score 0):

close the Android Studio and run android studio as administrator. This method works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem.

I accidentally deleted `PATH` variable in user variables and replaced it with another path.

But when I retrieved the original variable everything worked fine 
`PATH:%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`

Answer (score -1):

I have tried these solutions that will work in every case:

1. **Windows Bug** > Very Common issue caused by this BUG, try to turn off the Mobile Hotspot from settings before running the app.
2. Try to Close Extra software that are running in your PC, close chrome if needed, Invalidate cache and Restart the Android Studio. then Flutter Clean, Flutter Pub Get, Run App.
3. Try to **Delete .gradle** folder from android folder, Invalidate Cache and Restart Android Studio, Wait for Indexing and Then only start Building App.
4. If no One Worked from Above then simply **edit gradle.properties** file then,

find this line: `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M`

replace it with this: `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024M`

Answer (score -1):

**flutter SDK corrupted**

Sol:- I think your some file are corrupted in flutter SDK.
Delete old flutter folder and reinstall flutter SDK